# mysql loop to create single output

Tags: mysql

## the problem

I have a table `'purchase'` with an index `salesPersonNumber`, `productCode` and `purchaseID`. The `productCode` acts as a foreign key to another table `'product'` where there is an index **`price`**.

There is also another table `'purchase info'` with a key **`offerPrice`**. This table is composed of a composite key with keys `productCode` and `purchaseID`.

I am wanting to be able to add every **`price`** where the `salesPersonNumber = x` but if the **`offerPrice`** is `> 0` for the row to add that to the total (instead of the `price`).

Is there a way I could go about doing this with `mysql`?

## the atempt

Setting up the connections to the other tables:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `purchase` 
inner join `product` on purchase.productCode = product.productCode
inner join `purchase info` PI on purchase.productCode = PI.productCode AND purchase.purchaseID = PI.purchaseID
```

The final WHERE statement

```
WHERE salesPersonNumber = "'.$x.'"
```

---

Now I need to come up with a loop?

### Pseudo code

```
for each(number of rows belonging to salesPersonNumberX as row){
    if(row['offerPrice'] > 0){
        row['price'] = row['offerPrice'];
    }
    total += row['price'];
}
return total;
```

---

## Ts & Cs

This needs to be solely done in SQL!!†

† *apart from the variable `$x`*

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Without digging deeper into your schema, the easy answer is, use a case statement.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a conditional statement inside the `sum`:

Pseudo query:

`select sum(case when offer_price > 0 then offer_price else price end) from purchases;`